# CSS after property weird behavior with .X.Y type selectors

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I am not sure if this is expected for CSS `:after` pseudo class.

**What do I have ?**

I am trying to create a tooltip using CSS. Following is the HTML and CSS I am using. Fiddle [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/WYP29/)

**`HTML`**

```
<div class="tooltip tooltip-left">
        :(
</div>
```

**`CSS`**

```
.tooltip {
    display:inline-block;
    position:absolute;
    background: #002663;
    height:100px;
    width:300px;
    color:#fff;
    padding:20px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
/*TOP*/
.tooltip-top:after {
    content:"";
    display: block;
    position:absolute;  
    bottom:-20px;
    left:50%;
    border-top:20px solid #002663;
    border-left:20px solid transparent;
    border-right:20px solid transparent;
    margin-left:-20px;
};
/*LEFT*/
.tooltip-left:after {
    content:"";
    display: block;
    position:absolute;  
    right: -20px;
    top: 50%;
    border-left: 20px solid #002663;
    border-top: 20px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
    margin-top: -20px;
};
```

**What's so weird?**

The tooltip does not contain the arrow in the current fiddle. However if I comment the class `.tooltip-top:after` the arrow appears.

Why is this behavior? Cant I declare multiple definitions for `:after` pseudo element using different classes applied to same element?

Comment: Note that `:after` is not a pseudo-class, it is a pseudo-element. They are very different in terms of selector syntax - particularly you can't have more than one pseudo-element per selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a trailing semi colon after the .tooltip-top:after class. Remove it. It's causing the next class not to be read.

```
.tooltip-top:after {
    content:"";
    display: block;
    position:absolute;  
    bottom:-20px;
    left:50%;
    border-top:20px solid #002663;
    border-left:20px solid transparent;
    border-right:20px solid transparent;
    margin-left:-20px;
};  /* <-- This ; is what's causing the problem */
```

**[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/WYP29/1/)**

Comment: About time I go for eye testing. :| Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
  [data-tips] {
        position: relative;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
        [data-tips]:after,
        [data-tips]:before {
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 100;
            opacity: 0;
        }
            [data-tips]:after {
                content: attr(data-tips);
                height: 25px;
                line-height: 25px;
                padding: 0 10px;
                font-size: 12px;
                text-align: center;
                color: #fff;
                background: #222;
                border-radius: 5px;
                text-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
                -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
                -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
                box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
                white-space: nowrap;
                -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
                -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
                box-sizing: border-box;
            }
            [data-tips]:before {
                content: "";
                width: 0;
                height: 0;
                border-width: 6px;
                border-style: solid;
            }
                [data-tips]:hover:after,
                [data-tips]:hover:before {
                    opacity: 1;
                }
    /* Top tips */
    [data-tips].top-tip:after,
    [data-tips].top-tip:before {
        -webkit-transition: bottom 0.25s ease-in-out, opacity 0.25s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: bottom 0.25s ease-in-out, opacity 0.25s ease-in-out;
        transition: bottom 0.25s ease-in-out, opacity 0.25s ease-in-out;
        bottom: 90%;
        left: -9999px;
        margin-bottom: 12px;
    }
        [data-tips].top-tip:before {
            border-color: #222 transparent transparent transparent;
            margin-bottom: 0;
        }
        [data-tips].top-tip:hover:after,
        [data-tips].top-tip:hover:before {
            bottom: 100%;
            left: 0;
        }
        [data-tips].top-tip:hover:before {
            left: 15px;
        }
    /* Bottom tip */
    [data-tips].bottom-tip:after,
    [data-tips].bottom-tip:before {
        -webkit-transition: top 0.25s ease-in-out, opacity 0.25s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: top 0.25s ease-in-out, opacity 0.25s ease-in-out;
        transition: top 0.25s ease-in-out, opacity 0.25s ease-in-out;
        top: 90%;
        left: -9999px;
        margin-top: 12px;
    }
        [data-tips].bottom-tip:before {
            border-color: transparent transparent #222 transparent;
            margin-top: 0;
        }
        [data-tips].bottom-tip:hover:after,
        [data-tips].bottom-tip:hover:before {
            top: 100%;
            left: 0;
        }
        [data-tips].bottom-tip:hover:before {
            left: 15px;
        }
    /* Left tip */
    [data-tips].left-tip:after,
    [data-tips].left-tip:before {
        -webkit-transition: left 0.25s ease-in-out, opacity 0.25s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: left 0.25s ease-in-out, opacity 0.25s ease-in-out;
        transition: left 0.25s ease-in-out, opacity 0.25s ease-in-out;
        top: -9999px;
        left: 96%;
        margin-left: 12px;
    }
        [data-tips].left-tip:before {
            border-color: transparent #222 transparent transparent;
            margin-left: 0;
        }
        [data-tips].left-tip:hover:after,
        [data-tips].left-tip:hover:before {
            left: 100%;
            top: 0;
        }
        [data-tips].left-tip:hover:before {
            top: 7px;
        }
    /* Right tip */
    [data-tips].right-tip:after,
    [data-tips].right-tip:before {
        -webkit-transition: right 0.25s ease-in-out, opacity 0.25s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: right 0.25s ease-in-out, opacity 0.25s ease-in-out;
        transition: right 0.25s ease-in-out, opacity 0.25s ease-in-out;
        top: -9999px;
        right: 96%;
        margin-right: 12px;
    }
        [data-tips].right-tip:before {
            border-color: transparent transparent transparent #222;
            margin-right: 0;
        }
        [data-tips].right-tip:hover:after,
        [data-tips].right-tip:hover:before {
            right: 100%;
            top: 0;
        }
        [data-tips].right-tip:hover:before {
            top: 7px;
        }
```

HTML :

```
<a href="http://bavotasan.com" class="top-tip" data-tips="Go to bavotasan.com">bavotasan.com</a>
```

add the data-tips="" parameter to any HTML element plus a class to set the direction and a tooltip will appear.

Try following link : 
http://cbavota.bitbucket.org/css3-tips/

Comment: what is this and why?